# How to solve and read type error? ( nextJS + Auth.js)

Tags: authentication, next.js

I try to follow the documentation of next-auth.js. In the documentation I see the following Lazy initialization:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GitHub from "@auth/core/providers/github"

export const { handlers, auth } = NextAuth((req) => {
  console.log(req) // do something with the request
  return {
    providers: [GitHub],
  },
})
```

But while doing this I got a type error:

> Type error: Argument of type '(req: any) => { providers:
> OAuthConfig[]; secret: string | undefined; }' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'AuthOptions'.

How do I need to read and solve this? I already put an any type to the 'req' but it does not help.